# grab collection with related tables as sub collection - Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get a Collection, or array, that has a selected relationship as a sub collection:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
$user->box()->boxtype()->get();
```

Being that User has many-to-many relationship with Box, and Box has many-to-many with BoxType, I'd like to get a collection that would have all the BoxType results enbeded in the Box results collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read about [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) in the Laravel docs.  Also eager load constraints.